large number of heap allocations in database query results
I am implementing the Rows interface in sql/driver. When implementing the Next(dest []Value) error method, I found that when the result of data is very large, heap allocation will become a performance bottleneck. I did a test to illustrate this.
    b := binary.LittleEndian.AppendUint32(nil, 0)
    b = binary.LittleEndian.AppendUint16(b, 5)
    b = append(b, "hello"...)
    t := time.Now()
    var v driver.Value
    for i := 0; i < 100000000; i++ {
        v = b[5:11]
    }
    _ = v
    fmt.Println(time.Since(t))

Print execution time 4.154244695s.
cpu pprof
The pprof results show that too much time is spent in runtime.mallocgc because v = b[5:11] needs to allocate a slice header in the heap.
I want to know if there is a way to reduce the performance bottleneck caused by heap allocation. Or is there any other way to bypass it?

The value of b[5:11] is a slice, which is represented by a pointer and two integers. The slicing operation does not need to allocate memory.
Interfaces allocate a copy of the value on the heap when it doesn't fit into a single word, which the slice doesn't.
So
    s := b[5:11]

is cheap but
    var v any = s

needs to allocate memory. I'm afraid there is no way around this besides depending on Go internals.

Yes, you are right，but what does go internals mean?

Using the internal structures of any, like github.com/bytedance/sonic  does. I would advise against it,
